# Infopath 2003 from deployed to sharepoint moss 2007 - with win8 and infopath office 2013 error access to the following form template is required:

Tags: infopath, form, template

we have had an Infopath 2003 template with c# codebehind  deployed to sharepoint  moss 2007 website used with a doc library.

now when trying to download the template with windows 8 machein that has  infopath office 2013  this error happens

Form template: website url .........etc
To open the file, access to the following form template is required:

I would greatly appreciate any help.